# can't setup new copy of my existing octopress blog locally

Tags: github, octopress

I had an Octopress blog site set up well and hosted on Github, and it is still working well there.

Recently, I accidentally deleted local copy of it on my laptop. After that, I tries to retrieve a new copy to my laptop. But I executed a few commands without any caution, and now everything is messed things up.

I followed up instructions on [this page](http://blog.zerosharp.com/clone-your-octopress-to-blog-from-two-places/), but failed to get it up working again.

These are the files I got after I execute the first command on the page linked:

```
CHANGELOG.markdown  README.markdown     _config.yml     config.ru
Gemfile         Rakefile        config.rb       plugins
```

I don't see `public` and `source` folder.

When I run `rake generate` on terminal, it asks me to run `rake install`...

I am new to Ruby, but I think this isn't right for existing Octopress blog.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the local folder where you had it installed you could do `git remote -v` to list location of remote git.

Then you could do `git pull origin source`. If your remote git is called `origin` and your branch `source`.

If you removed the folder you could clone your repository. Go to github and find your git repository.

I wrote instructions on my blog here: http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2013/10/27/collaborating-on-a-github-blog-using-octopress/

Here is a summary of my post:

Clone the repository into the computer, create the `_deploy` directory and `git pull` into source and master branches:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:username/username.github.com.git
$ cd username.github.com
$ git checkout source
$ git pull origin source
$ mkdir _deploy
$ cd _deploy
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/username.github.com.git
$ git pull origin master
$ cd ..
```

Comment: So is it normal that I couldn't see my old posts locally at `localhost:4000` by running `rake preview` after doing all these?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to git hub you have 2 branches.

- master - branch which is the static blog and all it content
- source - (will be if you are deploying to username.github.io)
         If you use simple gh-pages you will only have local master with the content which needs to be pushed in order to have backup

If you did not pushed the source branch along with master you don't have any content to recover. You only have the generated blog.